# If string is within another string

Tags: php, string, parsing

Ok, so I am trying to detect whether a certain string is within another string, I have already tried using `explode` but it didn't work for obvious reasons, just so you can possibly get a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish, take a look at my failed attempt at using `explode` to try and solve my question

```
$stringExample1 = "hi, this is a example";

$stringExample2 = "hello again, hi, this is a example, hello again";

$expString = explode($stringExample1, $stringExample2);

if(isset($expString[1]))
{
    //$stringExample1 is within $stringExample2 !!
}
else
{
    //$stringExample1 is not within $stringExample2 :(
}
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `strpos` and `strstr` fails since you have extra comma in `example2` in second string. We can do the string match with regular expression. See the below code snippet for example.

```
<?php
$str1 = "hi, this is a example";
$str2 = "hello again, hi, this is a example, hello again";
$pattern = "/$str1/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $str2, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => hi, this is a example
        )

)
```

If count of output array (`$matches`) is greater than 0 then we have the match otherwise we don't have the match. You might need to tweak the regular expression created in `$pattern` to suit your need and may also need optimization.

Let us know if this works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

Comment: In my case $findme will include words separated by spaces... Will the use of strpos still work?

Comment: @JeffCoderr see my answer and let us know if that is what you are looking for or not. I have tested the both `strpos` and `strstr` they didn't work in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
if (strpos($stringExample2 , $stringExample1 ) !== false) {
  echo 'true';
}
```

or

[strstr](http://php.net/strstr)

```
if (strlen(strstr($stringExample2,$stringExample1))>0) {
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
```